# Installing geopandas uninstalls basemap & vice-versa

Tags: python-3.7, matplotlib-basemap, geopandas, anaconda3

I need a Python environment with both basemap and geopandas, but installing one removes the other. Is there anyway to have both, or is there a reasonable way to switch between interpreters in the same script?

I know basemap is being depreciated for cartopy, but I'm working with basemap and it is what is for now.

Using Anaconda3, Python 3.7.6

Here are the steps I have taken, just using the base environment:

```
conda install -c conda-forge basemap
conda install geopandas

## I kept having issues with installing geopandas:
## Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

## So I followed the solution by "forskamse" here [https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9367] 
conda activate base
conda config --set auto_update_conda False
conda install conda=4.6.14
conda install geopandas
```

This successfully installed geopandas, but it removed basemap:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:

  anaconda-2020.02-py37_0
  basemap-1.3.0-py37h7cd9bad_2
  python_abi-3.7-1_cp37m
```

Also confirmed basemap is removed by `conda list` inspection.

I have also tried a new environment as suggested on the [geopandas install page](https://geopandas.org/install.html), but I get a bunch of Solving environment errors installing joblib and scikit-learn... and maybe other libraries, I stopped trying at that point.

Comment: Is GeoPandas coming also from `conda-forge`? What is your OS? Doing `conda install -c conda-forge geopandas basemap` works for me.

Comment: @martinfleis Using Windows 10. I was mixing `conda` and `conda-forge` just like you noticed. I don't have a plain-English understanding of what the difference is between the two. But, using `conda install -c conda-forge geopandas basemap` also worked for me. Thank you, if you write it up as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different `conda` channels offer different compatibility and you should always try to stick to a single channel, either `defaults` or (preferably) `conda-forge`. Installing `geopandas` and `basemap` both from `conda-forge` should resolve the compatibility issue and allow you to instal both.

```
conda install -c conda-forge geopandas basemap
```

General advice for Python geospatial stack is stick to `conda-forge`.