# How to install python package in Anaconda environment when there is no channel installer

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, channel

I use Anaconda to manage my python environments. Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62477550/installing-geopandas-uninstalls-basemap-vice-versa), I try to stick to one channel in each environment.

I want to install [Beampy](https://pypi.org/project/beampy/). Based on the [Anaconda page for Beampy](https://anaconda.org/terradue/beampy), it looks like there is not a `conda-forge` channel, so I tried the default `conda` channel, but it looks like it's only availabe for Linux (I'm on Windows).

Can I run `pip install beampy-slideshow` in Anaconda Prompt, with my desired environment activated, or is it bad practice to mix pip install and conda channels? How can I install Beampy (or a suitable conda-friendly alternative)?

Answer (score 0):

You should just try:  `pip install beampy`.  This will search other channels until it finds it - if it can. Normally you shouldn't use pip with Andaconda but `conda install beampy` doesn't find the package.  Try loading with pip and see if it works.