# Trouble installing geopandas

Tags: python, geopandas

I have installed geopandas using the anaconda forge path. At first i got the message there is no “geopandas” module when trying the command “import geopandas.” I solved this to by using the path manager to connect to my “site packages” folder. But now when i import geopandas, i get the error “No module named ‘pyproj.__network’”. I am not sure how to resolve this because i have already tried setting a path to the folder where “pyproj” lives. Does anyone know how to remedy this? thank you!

Comment: does this help? [how to successfully install pyproj and geopandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34427788/how-to-successfully-install-pyproj-and-geopandas/51497039)

Comment: Also, see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62477550/installing-geopandas-uninstalls-basemap-vice-versa) as it explains the woes mixing different Anaconda channels. Try to set up a separate geospatial environment and use conda-forge.

Comment: I have just been using the conda-forge channel after creating a new env as outlined below. The forge channel without the environment causes me to be stuck "solving environment" https://geopandas.org/getting_started/install.html

Comment: when you type `conda list geopandas` in the command prompt, in your environment of interest, what is returned? and with `conda list pyproj`?

Comment: I get the following: 
'# packages in environment at C:\Users\dresc\anaconda3\envs\geo_env:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
geopandas                 0.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge'

Comment: And what does it return for pyproj?

Comment: I was able to get it to work in Jupyter notebooks, using this tutorial, it seems like Spyder wasn't properly synced with my envs.https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=how+to+tell+which+env+jupyter+notebooks+is+using&docid=608045546740925279&mid=B2C26C0481E95E33E1C1B2C26C0481E95E33E1C1&view=detail&FORM=VIRE